# Почему тернарный оператор выдает undefined в цикле?

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты, тернарный-оператор

Не могу понять, почему выходит такой ответ в этом цикле, скажите пожалуйста.

```js
$('input').keypress(function() {
  var obj = [{
      name: "Loki",
      surname: "Man"
    },
    {
      name: "Doki",
      surname: "Mon"
    },
    {
      name: "Fuka",
      surname: "Don"
    }
  ];

  var arr = obj.map((item) => {
    var otvet = item.name == 'Doki' ? console.log(item.name) : '';
    console.log(otvet);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что `console.log('item')` ничего не возвращает.

При выполнении условия в тернарном операторе Вы записываете в переменную `otvet` значение, которое возвращает вызов `console.log(...);`.

```js
$('input').keypress(function() {
  var obj = [
    {
      name: "Loki",
      surname: "Man"
    },
    {
      name: "Doki",
      surname: "Mon"
    },
    {
      name: "Fuka",
      surname: "Don"
    }
  ];

  var arr = obj.map(function(item) {
    if (item.name == 'Doki')
      return console.log(item.name); // надо return item.name;
    else
      return '';
  });
  console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input />
```

---

Демонстрация того, как переменной `otvet` присваивается значение `undefined`:

```js
function test() {
}
var otvet = true? test() : 'defined';
console.log(otvet);
```

Comment: Извиняюсь, я сделал поправку.

Comment: @ChingizMamedov, суть не поменялась

Comment: @ChingizMamedov `console.log(item.name)` тоже ничего не возвращает.

Comment: Тогда кто нибудь ответит не одним словом, а целым и ясным предложением?

Comment: Можно уточнить, как прописать именно через тернарный?

Comment: @ChingizMamedov Хорошо бы узнать, что Вы хотите сделать.

Comment: Ну, это примитивный случай. Мне надо проверять имя в оъектах и если имя совпадает, то выводить полную информацию. Но, хотел через тернарный. Так как не получается, теперь хочу понять суть, почему, если делать таким путем, то выводит undefined. Мне надо понимать есть ли конкретно момент, связанный с тернарным оператором, о котором я не знаю или логика моего кода не правильная.

Comment: @ChingizMamedov Я добавил в конце маленький пример, показывающий, откуда берется `undefined`.

Comment: Спасибо большое)